# Service Fabric Actor model with .Net Core- Fail to add actor nuget package

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

I have ServiceFabric/ActorModel project in .NetFramework and now I need to change that to .NetCore. I am following [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/service-fabric-dotnet-core-getting-started/) link and its example in Github, *CalculatorActor*

But I didnot manage to add *Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors* to my project.

> Package Microsoft.ServiceFabric 5.6.220 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.ServiceFabric 5.6.220 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>   Package Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data 2.6.220 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data 2.6.220 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>   Package Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services 2.6.220 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services 2.6.220 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>   Package Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting 2.6.220 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting 2.6.220 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>   Package Microsoft.ServiceFabric.FabricTransport.Internal 2.6.220 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.ServiceFabric.FabricTransport.Internal 2.6.220 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>   One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
>   Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for '...'.

It is a bit confusing if Microsoft support .net core for SF or not. Anyone has any experience in this migration path?

Comment: Package Microsoft.ServiceFabric 5.6.220 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.ServiceFabric 5.6.220 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5) 

It's not compatible, at least not that version is what NuGet is telling you.

Comment: I have tried almost all packages, even package that has been used in the GitHub project.

Comment: Before you start anything prepare your OS for service fabric - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started

Comment: thanks for the link. I have updated my SDK as mentioned on that page. But I still have the problem

Comment: Now follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore to understand how Service Fabric working with .Net Core and dont forget about `<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dnxcore50;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>` (you may need restart VS to apply this effect)

Comment: Here is the answer to this issue: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-core-getting-started/issues/4

Answer (score 1):

It literally says what the problem is in your error message.

Change your target to net standard 1.6 or a supported target.... have a gander at one of the example project's csproj files!

Comment: thanks for the comment ... this is what I have tried today.